My feature steps are being highlighted as Undefined, but the methods behind them run fine during execution?
I'm working with Cypress and decided to install Cucumber, ive created a feature file which successfully runs the step definitions in the Cypress runner but my cucumber steps are still being highlighted as Undefined in VS Code
Ive tried lots of different configs for the cypress.config.js file but cant get anything to work
There is a similar post in Stackoverflow but that solution wouldnt work for me as i dont use Intellij or TypeScript
Any help appreciated
Here are my dependencies:
    "@badeball/cypress-cucumber-preprocessor": "^21.0.2",
"@cypress/webpack-preprocessor": "^6.0.2",
"@testing-library/cypress": "^10.0.2",
"cypress": "^13.15.0",
"globals": "^15.11.0",
"webpack": "^5.96.1",
"webpack-cli": "^5.1.4",
"@bahmutov/cypress-esbuild-preprocessor": "^2.2.3"

Heres is my cypress.config.js


const createBundler = require("@bahmutov/cypress-esbuild- 
preprocessor");
const cucumberPreprocessor = require("@badeball/cypress-cucumber-preprocessor");
const esbuildPreprocessor = require("@badeball/cypress-cucumber-preprocessor/esbuild");

module.exports = {
  e2e: {
    specPattern: [
      'cypress/e2e/**/*.feature', // Define path to feature files
      'cypress/e2e/0-test/*.js', // Define path for regular specs
      // 'cypress/e2e/support/step_definitions/**/*.js', // Define the glue path
    ],
    stepDefinitions: 'cypress/e2e/support/step_definitions/**/*.js', // Explicitly set the path for step definitions
    async setupNodeEvents(on, config) {
      await cucumberPreprocessor.addCucumberPreprocessorPlugin(on, config);
      on(
        "file:preprocessor",
        createBundler({
          plugins: [esbuildPreprocessor.createEsbuildPlugin(config)],
        })
      );
      return config;
    },
  },
};



Here is my feature file


Feature: Example Feature

  Scenario: Example Scenario
    Given I visit the home page
    Then I should see the welcome message



Here are my step definitions


const { Given, Then } = require("@badeball/cypress-cucumber-preprocessor");

Given("I visit the home page", () => {
  debugger;
  cy.visit("https://example.com");
});

Then("I should see the welcome message", () => {
  cy.contains("Example Domain");
});



My folder structure


Please show the error that you are trying to solve. What does "highlighted as undefined" mean?

I've added a screenshot of the error
In VS Code, my Given & Then steps are underlined, saying its an 'undefined step', and i cant F12 to the step definition
